# Log all requests (GET, POST, etc.) for all resources (.aspx, .html, .jpg, etc.) to db/file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, logging, httphandler, httpmodule

Is it possible to log all requests (GET, POST, etc.) for all resources (.aspx, .html,.pdf, etc.) to db or file in ASP.NET 4 application?

For the moment we use following:

```
   public class RequestLogger : IHttpModule
   {
      public void Dispose()
      {

      }
      public void Init(HttpApplication context)
      {
         context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(mPreRequestHandlerExecute);
      }

      void mPreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(app.Request.InputStream);
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
      }
   }
```

This logger works but only for POST method, in other cases (GET) InputStream length is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get** request do not carry any information other than in url.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but are you sure about that? How do we then find out browser type, os type, supported encoding, etc. on the server side? Here is an example from fiddler: GET http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept: text/html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

Comment: This information is stored in request header. You can access them via `app.Request.Headers`.